# STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION due to malloc()?

Tags: c, exception, memory, status, access-violation

I am getting a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at run time in this C program I am creating, and I believe this is due to initialising structs all at once, and then using malloc() to increase their size, causing pointers to reference memory already in use.  This is the function where this exception occurs:

```
void process_track(char filename[], struct track *tracks) {
    int i = 0;
    FILE* fp;
    int lines;
    lines = count_file_lines(filename);
    tracks = malloc(lines);
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("\n\"%s\" File not found", filename);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d\n", &tracks[i].number, &tracks[i].startnode, &tracks[i].endnode, &tracks[i].minutes);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            printf("%d ", tracks[i].number);
            printf("%d ", tracks[i].startnode);
            printf("%d ", tracks[i].endnode);
            printf("%d\n", tracks[i].minutes);
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, it happens at the following line:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d\n", &tracks[i].number, &tracks[i].startnode, &tracks[i].endnode, &tracks[i].minutes);
```

The function is called in the following function (case 3):

```
void get_file(char textfilename[], int optnumber) {
    struct node *nodes;
    struct track *tracks;
    struct course *courses;
    struct entrant *entrants;
    struct checkpointdata *checkpointdatas;
    char filename[20]; //Array of char for filename
    printf("Enter the name of the %s text file(with file extension) :", textfilename);
    scanf(" %[a-zA-Z._1-9]", &filename);
    switch (optnumber) {
        case 1:
            process_name(filename);
            break;
        case 2:
            process_node(filename, nodes);
            break;
        case 3:
            process_track(filename, tracks);
            break;
        case 4:
            process_course(filename, courses);
            break;
        case 5:
            process_entrant(filename, entrants);
            break;
        case 6:
            process_checkpointdata(filename, checkpointdatas);
            break;
    }

}
```

It reads the first line fine, but fails after that.  Since the other "process_[data]" are very similar, I tried those too.  Some would work fine, some would also come up with the exception, and some would retrieve garbage on output.

How would I work around this, or allocate memory so that it does not clash with pre-allocated memory (if this indeed is the problem)?

Comment: You've forgotten to close the file you opened.  It has nothing to do with your crash, but you should learn good habits now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) accepts the number of bytes to allocate, not the number of elements. The posted code is only allocating `lines` bytes:

```
tracks = malloc(lines);
```

which is not enough for an array of `struct track` and will result in the subsequent `for` loops writing to and reading from beyond the bounds of the allocated memory block. Pass the size of the element as well as the number of elements:

```
tracks = malloc(lines * sizeof(*tracks));
```

Note that any change made to `tracks` within the function is visible only to that function. As `tracks` is not actually used after the call to the function the argument could be replaced with a local variable.

Remember for every `malloc()` there must be a [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free).

Comment: I understand now - thank you very much, that worked!  Regarding losing changes to `tracks`, why would the changes be lost outside the `process_track()` function as it is working from the `*tracks` pointer?  Does this mean I have to return the pointer?

Comment: @Wilko, pointers are also passed by value in C. To change what a pointer is pointing to in a function and have it visible outside the function you need to pass the address of the pointer. Or, you could return a pointer also.

Comment: Thanks for the further help!  Is there a reason I cannot change `process_track(filename, tracks);` to `process_track(filename, &tracks);` to pass the address to the function?

Comment: @Wilki, yes and change argument to `struct tracks**` and dereference `tracks` in the function: `*tracks = malloc(lines * sizeof(**tracks));`

Comment: I managed to actually wander onto changing those.  I changed the `.` operator to `->` to access the values at the pointer (e.g. `&tracks[i]->number`, but I am encountering `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` again now at the `fscanf()` line.  I thought that I would only need to dereference it then get the address of it, hence `*(*(&tracks[i]->number))`, or `*tracks[i]->number`, however the compiler is not liking it.

Comment: After more than 2 hours, still can't figure it out =[

Comment: @Wilko, see example here http://ideone.com/EpJrG1